# My prettier format breaking vue code (ref<number>(0)) with typescript

Tags: typescript, web, vuejs3, code-formatting, prettier

**Before Format:**

```
const activeIndex = ref<number>(0)
```

**After Format:**

```
const activeIndex = ref < number > 0
```

**Prettier Output:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO6dd.png)

**Prettier Config:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/prettierrc",
  "semi": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "printWidth": 100,
  "trailingComma": "none"
}
```

Can you suggest any solution or configuration that could help to resolve this issue? Thank you.

well, if i use `const activeIndex = ref(0)` which without type declaration, it would not cause this issue.

**WANTED:**
Prettier formatting do not change this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can try to add this to your config of prettier:

```
vueIndentScriptAndStyle: true,
```

Hope it works !

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your file named `blah.ts`? If it's `blah.js` the behaviour is correct.
2. Is your file `blah.vue`? Then if your `<script>` is not `<script lang="ts">` the behaviour is correct.

---

you should provide the whole file content cutted down to minimal reproducible example

Comment: sry, my file is vue and script tag is <script setup lang="ts">